# how to render html text with {{action}} as ember html inside a template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi I have computed property that returns an html link with an ember action like this:

externalHtmlLink:

```
<a {{action 'runService' 15001}} href="#">Click Here</a>
```

but if I render this inside the template like this:

```
{{{externalHtmlLink}}}
```

it renders the Action part as text and not as an Ember Html, and the action is never triggered.
How should I render the link so the action is rendered by Ember?

Comment: what version of ember-cli and ember-source are you using?

Comment: ember-cli: 3.0.4  ..... ember-source: "3.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

does rendering your component with only two sets of `{}` work?

e.g.:

```
{{externalHtmlLink}}
```

It's been a good number of years since this syntax

any chance I can encourage you to upgrade?

There is a guide here: https://emberjs.com/editions/octane/

Comment: with only two {{ }} the html is rendered as plain text... so no. And I cant upgrade, is not my decision

Comment: ah -- this exact thing is not possible then. you can't dynamic render components from strings unless you then also ship the template compiler -- similar to what https://limber.glimdown.com does